# Visual Code Studio and Markdown Extensions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, markdown

I am editing Markdown files using Visual Studio Code but I also use [Python extensions](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/).

How can I configure VS Code so its build-in Markdown preview to be able to display the effects of the extensions?

Comment: As far as I know, Visual Studio Code does not use the Python-Markdown as its Markdown parser. Therefore, extensions designed for Python-Markdown will not work with VSC. If you can determine which Markdown parser is used, then perhaps you could work out which extensions would be available, if any.

Comment: @Waylan I knew that but in the vs code documentation there is a section about customizing the preview so I thought there might be an easy solution. Thank you for the response though :)